# Node.js - how to read Environmental variables from Cloud Foundry application?

Tags: cloud-foundry, sap-cloud-foundry

I am working on the Node.js project and need to login to **Cloud Foundry and read environmental variables** (basically, credentials) of one application. So far, I was able to login and target the correct organization with the help of *'@sap/cf-tools'* package. Now, the last step remains, the equivalent of command

```
cf env APP_NAME
```

The problem is that *'@sap/cf-tools'* doesnt support yet this functionality and I haven't found any other which would do it. Did someone else face this problem and if yes, how did you solve it? Is there some npm package I have overlooked? Or I will be forced to run "cf env" with "-v" parameter and try to get to the desired EnvVariables through the series of axios calls? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use a series of Axios calls. Take a look at the following package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sap/xsenv. It should fit your use case.

```
var xsenv = require('@sap/xsenv');
var services = xsenv.readServices();
var svc = services[process.env.SERVICE_NAME];
```